# How can I use scalamock to stub WSRequestHolder.post() in Play

Tags: scala, playframework, scalamock

I'm having trouble using scalamock to stub the `post()` method in WSRequestHolder in the Play WS library.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
(request.post[Results.EmptyContent](_ : Results.EmptyContent)(_ : Writeable[Results.EmptyContent], _: ContentTypeOf[Results.EmptyContent])) when(Results.EmptyContent(), *,*) returns Future.successful(response)
```

The aim is to return `Future.successful(response)` when a `post()` is called with `Results.EmptyContent`.

The compiler error I'm getting is:

> value when is not a member of (play.api.mvc.Results.EmptyContent,
>   play.api.http.Writeable[play.api.mvc.Results.EmptyContent],
>   play.api.http.ContentTypeOf[play.api.mvc.Results.EmptyContent]) =>
>   scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.ws.WSResponse]
>        (request.post[Results.EmptyContent](_ : Results.EmptyContent)(_ : Writeable[Results.EmptyContent], _:
>   ContentTypeOf[Results.EmptyContent])).when(Results.EmptyContent(),
>   *,*) returns Future.successful(response)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

There is something going on here that I don't really understand. If I define the following trait:

```
  trait TestTrait {
    def post[T](data: T)(implicit wrt: Writeable[T], ct: ContentTypeOf[T]): Future[WSResponse]
  }
```

which has a `post()` method with the same signature as `WSRequestHolder.post()`, I can successfully stub it. So, there is some weirdness specific to `WSRequestHolder.post()` that is manifesting in this problem. Some nuance with regard to type inference maybe?

---

**UPDATE 2**

So, I've found a workaround. In my test, I define a new trait that extends `WSRequestHolder`:

```
trait StubbableWSRequestHolder extends WSRequestHolder {
  override def post[T](data: T)(implicit wrt: Writeable[T], ct: ContentTypeOf[T]): Future[WSResponse] =
    withMethod("POST").withBody(body).execute()
}
```

In my test, I create my stub from this trait. As you can see, unlike in `WSRequestHolder`, my overriden signature for `post()` is explicit about the return type of `Future[WSResponse]`.

The question remains, though, as to what exactly is going on here? Is this some kind of limitation with scalamock with regard to type inference?

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me what's going on here. Can you report a bug https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues ideally with a small project that reproduces the problem and we'll see if we can take a look.

Comment: Okay, done: https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues/87

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in the ScalaMock-3.2.1